# How to turn off the 'find me' FAB in Flutter Google maps plugin?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-flutter

I am having zero luck turning off the floating action button which exists on the Google maps view in Flutter.  I have tried restarting the app, hotreload, delete/reinstall, no luck.

[image: view showing FAB covering most of the map]

Here's my code:

```
return Card(
  child: GoogleMap(
    compassEnabled: false,
    mapToolbarEnabled: false,[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
    myLocationEnabled: false,
    initialCameraPosition: _curCamera,
    markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
    polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_polylines),
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
      staticMapController = controller;
      positionList = await tracksDB.getListOfPositions(widget.trackID);

      setState(() {
        _polylines.add(Polyline(
          polylineId: PolylineId('track1'),
          visible: true,
          points: positionList,
          color: Colors.red,
        ));
      });
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Setting the myLocationButtonEnabled to false should do the trick. But I see you already did that. Did you try this in the latest [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package?

Answer (score 0):

Latest package version fixed the problem.  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.3